# in Android, dynamically add a TextView to a ViewPager's ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've got a working `ViewPager` that uses Universal Image Loader and [ChrisBanes' PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) to pinch and zoom the images. In the PagerAdapter, the PhotoView is created and added to the ViewGroup in the `instantiateItem()` Object. I'm trying to add a `TextView` to display the image descriptions. Inflating an existing TextView doesn't seem to work because the descriptions aren't displayed. There are no errors in the LogCat in the below code, it just doesn't display. In my messing with the ViewPager, I've discovered that the TextView can't be in a separate layout from the ViewPagers ImageView or PhotoView. The text is not synched to the ImageView if the TextView and ImageViews are separate layouts.  So my question is **how can I dynamically add a TextView to the "container" `ViewGroup` of the below code?**

```
        @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        PhotoView phView = new PhotoView(container.getContext());
        // Attach a PhotoViewAttacher, which takes care of all of the
        // zooming functionality.
        mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(phView);
        final ProgressBar spinner = new ProgressBar(container.getContext());
        imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], phView, options,
                new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                            FailReason failReason) {
                        String message = null;
                        switch (failReason.getType()) {
                        case IO_ERROR:
                            message = "Input/Output error";
                            break;
                        case DECODING_ERROR:
                            message = "Image can't be decoded";
                            break;
                        case NETWORK_DENIED:
                            message = "Downloads are denied";
                            break;
                        case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                            message = "Out Of Memory error";
                            break;
                        case UNKNOWN:
                            message = "Unknown error";
                            break;
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), message,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                            View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

        //--- adding the TextView
        View textviewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_t, container,false);
        TextView txt = (TextView) textviewLayout.findViewById(R.id.redtext_pagertxml_tv);

        txt.setText(imTitlesStr[position]);
        container.addView(phView, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        return phView;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, dynamically adding a `TextView` isn't the answer. I ended up creating a `FrameLayout` for the `ViewGroup` to use.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<uk.co.senab.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/uilpv_pv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/uilpv_tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:background="#A0449def"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see in the XML, I'm using `ChrisBanes' PhotoView` instead of an `ImageView`, so then in `instantiateItem()` call the `PhotoView` like so:

```
        @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
        View imageLayout = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.uil_pager_item, view, false);
        PhotoView pHview = (PhotoView) imageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.uilpv_pv);
        mAttacher = new PhotoViewAttacher(pHview);

        imageLoader.displayImage(images[position], pHview, options,
                new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                        // spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                            FailReason failReason) {
                        String message = null;
                        switch (failReason.getType()) {
                        case IO_ERROR:
                            message = "Input/Output error";
                            break;
                        case DECODING_ERROR:
                            message = "Image can't be decoded";
                            break;
                        case NETWORK_DENIED:
                            message = "Downloads are denied";
                            break;
                        case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                            message = "Out Of Memory error";
                            break;
                        case UNKNOWN:
                            message = "Unknown error";
                            break;
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(UILPager.this, message,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                            View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        // spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });

        TextView txt = (TextView) imageLayout.findViewById(R.id.uilpv_tv);
        txt.setText(imTitlesStr[position]);

        ((ViewPager) view).addView(imageLayout, 0);
        return imageLayout;
    }
```

And for my project, this solution works exactly the way it's supposed to.